# community engine desert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, communityengine

i tried install community engine. 
problem: 
You passed :lib as an option for gem 'desert', but it is invalid.

my desert gem:
desert (0.5.4)

help please..
log:

```
home@home-desktop:~$ rails new wbce -m https://raw.github.com/bborn/communityengine/edge/community_engine_setup_template.rb
      create  
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/images/rails.png
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/mailers
      create  app/models
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/mailers/.gitkeep
      create  app/models/.gitkeep
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  doc
      create  doc/README_FOR_APP
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.gitkeep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.gitkeep
      create  log
      create  log/.gitkeep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/index.html
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  script
      create  script/rails
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.gitkeep
      create  test/functional
      create  test/functional/.gitkeep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.gitkeep
      create  test/unit
      create  test/unit/.gitkeep
      create  test/performance/browsing_test.rb
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.gitkeep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.gitkeep
      create  vendor/plugins
      create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
       apply  https://raw.github.com/bborn/communityengine/edge/community_engine_setup_template.rb
  Please enter the application's name:  WBCE
         run    rm public/index.html from "."
         run    git init from "."
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/home/wbce/.git/
         run    git add . from "."
         run    touch tmp/.gitignore log/.gitignore vendor/.gitignore from "."
         run    find . -type d -empty | grep -v "vendor" | grep -v ".git" | grep -v "tmp" | xargs -I xxx touch xxx/.gitignore from "."
    conflict    .gitignore
  Overwrite /home/home/wbce/.gitignore? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] 
       force    .gitignore
     gemfile    desert
     gemfile    rmagick
     gemfile    hpricot
     gemfile    htmlentities
     gemfile    haml
     gemfile    aws-s3
     gemfile    calendar_date_select
     gemfile    ri_cal
     gemfile    authlogic
     gemfile    searchlogic
     gemfile    rakismet
        rake    gems:install
[sudo] password for home: 
You passed :lib as an option for gem 'desert', but it is invalid.
      plugin    community_engine
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/home/wbce/vendor/plugins/community_engine/.git/
remote: Counting objects: 17261, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (6043/6043), done.
remote: Total 17261 (delta 11405), reused 16199 (delta 10653)
Receiving objects: 100% (17261/17261), 6.05 MiB | 333 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (11405/11405), done.
         run    git submodule init from "."
Submodule 'vendor/plugins/community_engine' (git://github.com/bborn/communityengine.git) registered for path 'vendor/plugins/community_engine'
         run    git submodule update from "."
 [CE SETUP] Checking out the edge branch 

         run    git checkout --track -b edge origin/edge from "./vendor/plugins/community_engine"
Branch edge set up to track remote branch edge from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'edge'
       route    map.routes_from_plugin :community_engine
 [CE SETUP] Modifying your environment.rb and environments files to work with CE 

        gsub    config/environment.rb
      append    config/environment.rb
 [CE SETUP] Modifying environment files ... 

  Please enter the url where you plan to deploy this app (use 'example.com' for now if you don't know yet): 
      create    config/application.yml
    generate    plugin_migration
You passed :lib as an option for gem 'desert', but it is invalid.
        rake    db:create:all
You passed :lib as an option for gem 'desert', but it is invalid.
        rake    db:migrate
You passed :lib as an option for gem 'desert', but it is invalid.
      capify    
         run    git add . from "."
         run    git commit -a -m 'Initial commit' from "."
[master (root-commit) efde59c] Initial commit
 38 files changed, 870 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 .gitignore
 create mode 100644 .gitmodules
 create mode 100644 Gemfile
 create mode 100644 README.rdoc
 create mode 100644 Rakefile
 create mode 100644 app/assets/images/rails.png
 create mode 100644 app/assets/javascripts/application.js
 create mode 100644 app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
 create mode 100644 app/controllers/application_controller.rb
 create mode 100644 app/helpers/application_helper.rb
 create mode 100644 app/mailers/.gitkeep
 create mode 100644 app/models/.gitkeep
 create mode 100644 app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
 create mode 100644 config.ru
 create mode 100644 config/application.rb
 create mode 100644 config/application.yml
 create mode 100644 config/boot.rb
 create mode 100644 config/database.yml
 create mode 100644 config/environment.rb
 create mode 100644 config/environments/development.rb
 create mode 100644 config/environments/production.rb
 create mode 100644 config/environments/test.rb
 create mode 100644 config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
 create mode 100644 config/initializers/inflections.rb
 create mode 100644 config/initializers/mime_types.rb
 create mode 100644 config/initializers/secret_token.rb
 create mode 100644 config/initializers/session_store.rb
 create mode 100644 config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
 create mode 100644 config/locales/en.yml
 create mode 100644 config/routes.rb
 create mode 100644 db/seeds.rb
 create mode 100644 doc/README_FOR_APP
 create mode 100644 lib/assets/.gitkeep
 create mode 100644 lib/tasks/.gitkeep
 create mode 100644 log/.gitignore
 create mode 100644 log/.gitkeep
 create mode 100644 public/404.html
 create mode 100644 public/422.html
 create mode 100644 public/500.html
 create mode 100644 public/favicon.ico
 create mode 100644 public/robots.txt
 create mode 100755 script/rails
 create mode 100644 test/fixtures/.gitkeep
 create mode 100644 test/functional/.gitkeep
 create mode 100644 test/integration/.gitkeep
 create mode 100644 test/performance/browsing_test.rb
 create mode 100644 test/test_helper.rb
 create mode 100644 test/unit/.gitkeep
 create mode 100644 tmp/.gitignore
 create mode 100644 vendor/.gitignore
 create mode 100644 vendor/assets/javascripts/.gitkeep
 create mode 100644 vendor/assets/stylesheets/.gitkeep
 create mode 100644 vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
 create mode 160000 vendor/plugins/community_engine
SUCCESS!
Next, you should probably run `rake test` and `rake community_engine:test` and make sure all tests pass. 
         run  bundle install
You passed :lib as an option for gem 'desert', but it is invalid.
home@home-desktop:~$
```

gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'json'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug'

gem "desert", :lib => "desert"
gem "rmagick", :lib => "RMagick"
gem "hpricot", :lib => "hpricot"
gem "htmlentities", :lib => "htmlentities"
gem "haml", :lib => "haml"
gem "aws-s3", :lib => "aws/s3"
gem "calendar_date_select"
gem "ri_cal"
gem "authlogic"
gem "searchlogic"
gem "rakismet"
```

version community engine:
https://github.com/bborn/communityengine
short version

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us your `Gemfile`? Sounds like the error is something in that file, probably a `lib` that should be a `require` for Bundler.

What version of CommunityEngine are you using?

Comment: Try changing all the `lib` to `require` in the Gemfile.

But you didn’t answer what version of CommunityEngine you’re using. I suspect you’re not using [the one that’s for Rails 3.2](https://github.com/bborn/communityengine/tree/rails3) because this `lib` business shouldn’t be happening in a recent Rails application.